# java 8 process memory analysis(Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, memory-management, java-8, jvm

Tomcat : apache-tomcat-8.0.21 
Java : 1.8.0_91-b14

We have a tomcat deployed with few wars. We are using java 8 version. We want to track the different memory regions and compare it with physical memory(ram) used by the application.

**Our observation:**
Physical memory(RAM) used: 2070M 
Heap: 1024M 
Metaspace: ~200M 
Thread(Stacks): ~116M 
Code: ~117M 
GC related: ~90M 
Others as per jcmd output(Compiler+Internal+Symbol+NMT+Arena chunk+unknown): ~45MB

Adding up the memory regions, it is around 1592M. But this is not equal to 2070M i.e. physical memory(RAM) used.

How can we track the unknown memory, 478M(= 2070M - 1592M)? In the data posted here the difference is 478M, but I can see the difference go upto 1500M. How to track/measure other memory regions. How to track native memory, byte buffers?

Following are some data about application configuration and monitoring tool(like jstat, jcmd) output. Please let me know if any other data is required.

**jvm specific values**

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1g  -Xmx1g  -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/tomcat0/temp/heap_dump_${date}.hprof 
-verbose:gc -XX:+UseG1GC -Xloggc:/opt/tomcat0/logs/gc.log 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20 -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail 
-XX:+StartAttachListener"
```

**unix htop command output**:- ram consumption is 2070mb.
[image: unix htop command output]

**jcmd native memory statistics**

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/jcmd 22190 VM.native_memory summary
22190:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=2804603KB, committed=1626391KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB) 

-                     Class (reserved=1229991KB, committed=205991KB)
                            (classes #34804)
                            (malloc=5287KB #65986) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1224704KB, committed=200704KB) 

-                    Thread (reserved=116338KB, committed=116338KB)
                            (thread #113)
                            (stack: reserved=115136KB, committed=115136KB)
                            (malloc=368KB #565) 
                            (arena=834KB #224)

-                      Code (reserved=270143KB, committed=117979KB)
                            (malloc=20543KB #26939) 
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=97436KB) 

-                        GC (reserved=90059KB, committed=90059KB)
                            (malloc=18379KB #80926) 
                            (mmap: reserved=71680KB, committed=71680KB) 

-                  Compiler (reserved=393KB, committed=393KB)
                            (malloc=262KB #777) 
                            (arena=131KB #3)

-                  Internal (reserved=15328KB, committed=15328KB)
                            (malloc=15296KB #70770) 
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB) 

-                    Symbol (reserved=19510KB, committed=19510KB)
                            (malloc=15858KB #174053) 
                            (arena=3652KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=6889KB, committed=6889KB)
                            (malloc=255KB #3982) 
                            (tracking overhead=6633KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=5329KB, committed=5329KB)
                            (malloc=5329KB) 

-                   Unknown (reserved=2048KB, committed=0KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=2048KB, committed=0KB)
```

**Jstat cmd for metaspace capacity and usage**

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/jstat -gc 22190
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   11264.0    0.0    1037312.0  1036942.5  200704.0 195572.8 24832.0 23916.7   9140  403.122 1832  6057.159 6460.280
```

**Jstat cmd for class stats**

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/jstat -class 22190
Loaded  Bytes  Unloaded  Bytes     Time   
 38219 69583.9     3360  4243.3     180.27
```

Comment: try MBeans for directbytebuffer memory and `pmap -x` for mapped files.

Comment: @the8472 how to interpret pmap with java memory regions? and pmap shows the exact ram usage.

Comment: Looks like you already have your answer: look at the "native memory statistics". Trying to figure out what the JVM is doing, especially with memory management, is a bit of a Black Art.